# Cannot call .Schedule() in Unity Job System

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I am using the Unity Job System for the first time and it seems that all `IJob` structs do not have the `.Schedule()` methods on them, only `.Execute()`. Here is the job I am using:

```
[BurstCompile(CompileSynchronously = true)]
public struct ConvertBytesToSBytesJob: IJob
        {
            public NativeArray<byte> bytes;
            public NativeArray<sbyte> sbytes;

            public void Execute()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    sbytes[i] = (sbyte)bytes[i];
                }
            }
        }
```

```
NativeArray<byte> bytes = new NativeArray<byte>();
                bytes.CopyFrom(_camBytes);
                ConvertBytesToSBytesJob convertBytesToSBytesJob = new ConvertBytesToSBytesJob
                {
                    bytes = bytes,
                };
                convertBytesToSBytesJob.Schedule();
```

Visual Studio error:

```
'ConvertBytesToSBytesJob' does not contain a definition for 'Schedule' and no accessible extension method 'Schedule' accepting a first argument of type 'Utils.ConvertBytesToSBytesJob' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Visual Studio shows I can call `.Execute()` but not `.Schedule()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Schedule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.IJobExtensions.Schedule.html) is an extension method implemented in [`IJobExtensions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.IJobExtensions.html) ([source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Jobs/Managed/IJob.cs)) so if you are using `Unity.Jobs` it should be found automatically.

In the file where you are wanting to schedule that job, you should have

```
using Unity.Jobs;
```

on top of the file.

Comment: That's it. I didn't have it in the scope I was calling ```.Schedule()```. Thank you!